# isEmpty returning false for empty set

Tags: scala

In this code

```
    def findQuestionCreatedCount(transaction:DistributedTransaction,userId:UUID,tagSet:Set[String]):Future[List[(String,Int)]]={
        logger.trace(s"will find questions created portfolio for ${userId} and tagSet ${tagSet}. tagSet empty ${tagSet.isEmpty}")
        if(tagSet.isEmpty == false) { //set has data
      ...
}
```

I see print `will find questions created portfolio for 3455c2b9-37f2-4373-9dcd-9e71b43e8c3d and tagSet Set(). tagSet empty false`

How come tagSet is `Set()` yet its empty value is `false`? Shouldn't it be true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possibly there is an empty string `""` inside the set so it is not visible when printed, for example consider

```
scala> Set("").toString
val res0: String = Set()

scala> Set("").isEmpty
val res1: Boolean = false
```

You could confirm if that is the case like so

```
tagSet.contains("")
```

As a side note consider how `stringOf` prints it

```
scala> scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime.stringOf(Set(""))
val res0: String = Set("")
```

Also [PPrint](https://github.com/lihaoyi/PPrint) would print strings with surrounding quotes visible, for example

```
println(Set(""))
pprint.pprintln(Set(""))
println("")
pprint.pprintln("")
```

outputs

```
Set()
Set("")

""
```